# backbone javascript setTimeOut method

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, backbone.js, settimeout

im have a problem with method setTimeOut that call the function self and set a delay, the function should be called again and again after every request is done but it only runs once. It works without using backbone.js tho, don't know it doesnt work after integration with backbone.js. Any help is appreciated!

So this is a function in client that runs a GET request gets data from server, the request runs in a time interval(decided in the server), as soon as a data comes in, client gets it and the request runs again after.

```
    getRequest:function() {
        var XHR = $.ajax({
            url: '/nextdocument',
            type: 'GET',
            async: true,
            cache: false,
            timeout: 11000, 
            success:function(data) {
                var name = data.description;
                var price = data.price;
                console.log("read--> " + name + price);
                setTimeout("this.getRequest", 1000);
                if (data.ok == "true") {
                    data["ok"] = data.ok;
                    $.ajax(
                        {
                            url: "/customerdone",
                            data: JSON.stringify(data),
                            processData: false,
                            type: 'POST',
                            contentType: 'application/json'
                        }
                    )
                }else{
                    //no document if no read in
                    console.log("error--> " + data.errorMessage)
                }
            }
        })
        return XHR;
    }
```

Comment: what do you mean by :
if (data.ok == 'true') {
   data['ok'] = data.ok;
           .
           .
}
? is it needed?

Comment: In setTimeout, don't use a string, use an anonymous function like `setTimeout(function() { namespace.getRequest() },1000);` "namespace" is a placeholder for whatever the name of your package is that wraps getRequest.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're using "this" in your `setTimeout` call. You can't do this because "this" will be the global object when the timer executes the function you're trying to reference.

like others have suggested, you need to pass an actual function to your timer, not a string. then you can reference whatever function from whatever object you want.

Answer (score 0):

probably, the function getRequest isn't being called. This is, as far as I think, because you are sending a string -- "this.getRequest" to the setTimeout function. As a rule of thumb, never pass string to this, pass functions. Although, it might be perfectly ok in some situations (i'd never recommend it anyway), here 'this' might be causing trouble. Use something like this:

```
getRequest:function() {
    var fn = arguments.callee;
    var XHR = $.ajax({
        url: '/nextdocument',
        type: 'GET',
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        timeout: 11000, 
        success:function(data) {
            var name = data.description;
            var price = data.price;
            console.log("read--> " + name + price);
            setTimeout(fn, 1000);
            if (data.ok == "true") {
                data["ok"] = data.ok;
                $.ajax(
                    {
                        url: "/customerdone",
                        data: JSON.stringify(data),
                        processData: false,
                        type: 'POST',
                        contentType: 'application/json'
                    }
                )
            }else{
                //no document if no read in
                console.log("error--> " + data.errorMessage)
            }
        }
    })
    return XHR;
}
```

Comment: OT: consider splitting the callbacks into functions for keeping code more readable and maintainable.